# Is addicted an action verb?

Tags: verbs

Is the word *"addicted"* an action verb?

**"Rubetta has been *addicted* to meth for 12 years of her life, losing custody of all of her children as a result."**

Comment: It's been a while since I have had to do this kind of parsing, but technically, I don't think that **addicted** is even a verb in that sentence.  It looks more like an adjective.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a verb at all.

It's an adjective describing "Rubetta"

the verb in you sentence is "been".

Source: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/addicted

Comment: Exactly. But 'the verb' is either *has* or *has been*, depending on what grammatical sect you profess.

Answer (score 2):

If "addicted" is an action verb, then "has been addicted" is a passive voice construction, and we should be able to find the active voice equivalent.

> Someone or something has addicted Rubetta to meth.

I would say that *to addict* is an action verb and that it is transitive.  I would also say that it is rarely used in its capacity as a verb.  "Addicted" is both the past tense form and the so-called past participle form.  The participle is commonly used as a modifier.  One parsing of the original sentence marks "has been addicted" as a present tense, perfect aspect, indicative mode and passive voice action verb.  An alternate parsing would mark "addicted to meth for twelve years of her life" as a predicate adjectival subject complement participial phrase, and "has been" as a present tense, perfect aspect, indicative mode linking verb.  I don't see any reason to prefer one parsing to the other.

Is "addicted" an action verb?  Yes, but not often and not necessarily.